# How to perform fstrim on a loop device?

Tags: mount, lvm, fstrim, thinpool

I have LVM with thin-provisioning enabled. I have two almost identical thin logical volumes with ext4 file systems that slightly differs. The first volume is used entirely for storing file system. On the second volume file system is stored with a small offset. It is mounted with `-o offset=1048576` option.

First volume could be cleaned with the `fstrim` command, but the second one could not. It gives the error instead:

```
fstrim: second: the discard operation is not supported
```

That is because of offset mounting I believe. Receiving offset option mount command creates temporary loop device and mounts it. So the main suspect is loop device.

Is it possible somehow to clean filesystem that has offset to the volume start block address?

Comment: Versions of your kernel and OS please :-). This is supposed to be supported as of Linux 3.2.  https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2012/02/15/discard-hole-punching-and-trim/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible. I tried to find out why - this is a comment from [`loop.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/block/loop.c#L765):

```
        /*
         * If the backing device is a block device, mirror its zeroing
         * capability. Set the discard sectors to the block device's zeroing
         * capabilities because loop discards result in blkdev_issue_zeroout(),
         * not blkdev_issue_discard(). This maintains consistent behavior with
         * file-backed loop devices: discarded regions read back as zero.
         */
```

LVM thin devices do NOT report zeroing capability (`write_zeroes_max_bytes` is `0`). I specifically checked `dm-thin.c` to confirm it.